# How to actually save a csv file to google drive from colab?

Tags: pandas, csv, save, google-colaboratory, drive

so, this problem seems very simple but apparently is not.
I need to transform a pandas dataframe to a csv file and save it in google drive.

My drive is mounted, I was able to save a zip file and other kinds of files to my drive.
However, when I do:

```
df.to_csv("file_path\data.csv")
```

it seems to save it where I want, it's on the left panel in my colab, where you can see all your files from all your directories. I can also read this csv file as a dataframe with pandas in the same colab.

**HOWEVER**, when I actually go on my Google Drive, I can never find it! but I need a code to save it to my drive because I want the user to be able to just run all cells and find the csv file in the drive.

I have tried everything I could find online and I am running out of ideas!
Can anyone help please?

I have also tried this which creates a visible file named data.csv but i only contains the file path

```
import csv
with open('file_path/data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
  csvfile.write('file_path/data.csv')
```

HELP :'(

**edit** :

```
import csv

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Datatourisme/tests_automatisation/data_tmp.csv') as f:
    s = f.read()

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Datatourisme/tests_automatisation/data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
  csvfile.write(s)
```

seems to do the trick.

1. First export as csv with pandas (named this one data_tmp.csv),
2. then read it and put that in a variable,
3. then write the result of this "reading" into another file that I named data.csv,

this data.csv file can be found in my drive :)

**HOWEVER** when the csv file I try to open is too big (mine has 100.000 raws), it does nothing.
Has anyone got any idea?

Comment: Try using `pd.to_csv("./drive/My Drive/filename.csv")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!   

it doesn't work for me sadly.      



my file path is '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datatourisme/tests_automatisation/data1.csv'.      
As I said my code and some others I've tried work kind of... But my csv file remains invisible when I go out of colab and actually go on my Drive.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, mount your Google Drive with the Colab:

   `from google.colab import drive`

   `drive.mount('/content/drive')`
2. Allow Google Drive permission
3. Save your data frame as CSV using this function:

   `import pandas as pd`

   `filename = 'filename.csv'`

   `df.to_csv('/content/drive/' + filename)`

In some cases, directory `'/content/drive/'` may not work, so try `'content/drive/MyDrive/'`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
df.to_csv( "/Drive Path/df.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer :) I do know how to do a df.to_csv. It works, it just won't be saved in my drive. I have found since then that this is a Google Colab / Google Drive problem and there is not much I can do apparently :/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use pandas to work with data in python, works very well.

In that case, here is a simple tutorial, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html [Pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Then to save your data frame to drive, if you have your drive already mounted, use the function to_csv

dataframe.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/'filename.csv'", index=False), will do the trick